# Ensure clause in Eiffel regarding across syntax

Tags: eiffel

```
 find(c: CHARACTER; position: INTEGER): INTEGER
```

This feature finds a character by starting at position i and searching. Once it finds the index it outputs it. However if no such character exists in the word then 0 is output

**Question:**
The postcondition must assert that the query returns the index of a character c in word in range pos .. word.count, or zero if there is no such character.

**My Code:**

```
find(c: CHARACTER; position: INTEGER): INTEGER
   require
            .....
   do

            .....
   ensure 
        across word as w
        some
             (w.item = c and w.cursor_index >= position)
        end
   end
```

Problem with this boolean equality is that when find(c,pos) is used and nothing is found the feature throws a post-condition violation.

I'm trying to make it allow the feature to output ONLY when the given c character does not exist in the word

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand correctly the question, but for your postcondition, you can do someting like:   Result = 0 or else (Result >= position and word.at(Result) = c)

Comment: No that won't work because I can't output integers it only takes boolean value

Comment: Then I don't understand your function `find'. It has an INTEGER Result type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that it should be a complete postcondition, let's look at the problem on a case-by-case basis:

1. Q. What is the allowed range of output values?
   A. The result can be `0` or any valid position in the `word` starting from `position`:

   ```
   valid_result_range: Result = 0 or position <= Result and Result <= word.count
   ```

   Here we assume that `position` is non-negative (hopefully this is specified in the precondition).
2. Q. What is the output value if there are no matching characters?
   A. The output is `0`. All characters with indexes starting from `position` do not match:

   ```
   zero_if_not_found: (Result = 0) =
       across word as wc all
           position <= wc.target_index implies wc.item /= c
       end
   ```
3. Q. What is the output value if there is a matching character?
   A. It is the first position of the corresponding character starting from `position`:

   ```
   non_zero_if_found: (Result /= 0) implies
      (
         word [Result] = c
      and
         across word as wc all
            (position <= wc.target_index and w.target_index < Result) implies
            wc.item /= c
         end
      )
   ```

   This postcondition has two parts. One checks that the character is found. The other checks that there are no matching characters before that position.
   **EDIT:** The original code started with `(Result /= 0) = ...` instead of `(Result /= 0) implies ...`. This would cause assertion violation in `word [Result]` when `Result = 0`. The code with `implies` if free from this issue because if an expression before `implies` is `False` then an expression after it is not evaluated.

The final postcondition is the combination of all the assertions above. The order of assertions is important because `non_zero_if_found` relies on the fact that `Result` is a valid index for `word`.

Comment: Just wondering, is there no reason to put "wc.target_position <= word.count"? Does the iterator do it by itself?

Comment: @GeForce, an `across` loop runs through all valid indexes only, therefore there is no need to check that the current index is a valid one, in this case in the range `1`..`word.count`.

Answer (score 1):

I would change Alexander's answer very slightly:

zero_if_not_found: (Result = 0) implies ...
non_zero_if_found: (Result /= 0) implies ...

To see why, consider what happens when Result = 0 and we evaluate Alexander's non_zero_if_found:

(Result /= 0) evaluates to False
Then word [Result] = c evaluates to a precondition failure (valid_index - I'm assuming word is a STRING type). (changing w [Result] to word [Result] as that was a typo by Alexander, i think)

Using implies protects you against this, as the RHS doesn't get evaluated.

Comment: Indeed there was a mistake in my code for `non_zero_if_found`, it is corrected now. As to adding `implies` to `zero_if_not_found`, leaving the equality seems better to me, because then we know when `Result` is `0` directly from the assertion and it is safe to use equality in this case. Thank you!

Comment: OK. Looks like target_position is another typo for target_index?